# Getting KeyError: 'WINDOWSSDKDIR' while running Chromium browser source code on Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, chromium

MAIN OBJECTIVE: I'm trying to build and run Chromium browser source code on my Windows. I want to create my own browser. The doc I'm following: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

PROBLEM: I'm trying to follow every step and command as mentioned in the doc. I'm having trouble while running this command `gn gen out/Default`. I'm getting the following error (see the screenshot):

`KeyError: 'WINDOWSSDKDIR'`
`ERROR at //build/config/win/visual_studio_version.gni:27:7: Script returned non-zero exit code.`

Here is vs_toolchain.py: https://github.com/arkadee/demo_files/blob/master/vs_toolchain.py

[image]

I'm using the latest version of VS Code. I've tried finding the solution myself, but, there are limited resources on the internet about Chromium. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Looks like `WindowsSdkDir` env variable is missing on your computer. You should install Visual Studio (VS Code is different) and the Window SDK, though it doesn't use VC compiler or linker anymore but `GN` build system needs the path of Windows SDK to copy all the relevant files to the build folder. Go to command prompt and type `set`, do you see `WindowsSdkDir` env variable? If not then either the SDK is missing or the env variable has been wiped out

Comment: If it solved your problem then please let us know. So that it will be helpful to others too

Comment: Great, I have posted that solution as an answer to your question. So please don't forget to mark it as your answer, so that it will be helpful to others too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `WindowsSdkDir` env variable is missing on your computer. You should install Visual Studio (VS Code is different) and the Window SDK, though it doesn't use VC compiler or linker anymore but `GN` build system needs the path of Windows SDK to copy all the relevant files to the build folder. Go to command prompt and type `set`, do you see `WindowsSdkDir` env variable? If not then either the SDK is missing or the env variable has been wiped out